# MySQL query across two connections

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to query across two connections in MySql? Or is there a MSSQL "linked server" equivalent?

My goal is this is pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM prd_connection.schema.t_table
INTO dev_connection.schema.t_table_dev
```

Comment: That question is about using PHP and the answer is about 2 databases, not two connections.

Comment: Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html. Not sure if this is what you need but might help.